# PL/SQL simple select into record variable

Tags: sql, select, data-structures, plsql, record

I have declared a record variable:

```
Declare
TYPE WORK_REC IS RECORD(
STRING1  VARCHAR (21),  
NUMBER1  NUMBER  (05)
);
TARGET_REC WORK_REC;
...
```

At certain point I get two values that I have to move to my record variable.
Is it possible to use a single SELECT INTO like this?

```
SELECT (<PROPER STRING VALUE> , <PROPER NUMBER VALUE> ) INTO TARGET_REC
```

The point here is I'd like to fill my record in a simple maintaining way.

Comment: The intention is to simplify - if I have to change my record's structure, I think It would be easier to change this part where its values are assigned.

Comment: I don't use 'from' because my data didn't come from a table - They're simple values, like parameters or values obtained from operations during de process.

Comment: But a `from` clause is a mandatory part of the syntax. You can't just skip it because they are only variables.

Comment: why not just use select ... from dual;

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do that. As long as the columns selected matches the target variables in both number and type.

```
create table rec_test( s1 varchar2(21), n1 number(5));
insert into rec_test (s1,n1) values('ABC',2) ;

declare 
  type work_rec is record(
       string1  varchar2 (21),  
       number1  number  (05)
       );
  target_rec work_rec;
begin
  select s1, n1
    into target_rec 
    from rec_test;

  dbms_output.put_line( 'rec=(' || target_rec.string1 || ',' || target_rec.number1 || ')' ); 
end ;
```

Comment: Good, but my values didn't come from a table - they are simple variables that I got from string operations or arithmetic operations. Your example fill the record with a record

Comment: Then you do need a select at all, just simple assignment. work_rec.string1 := <proper_string_value>; work_rec.number1 := <proper_number_value>;  You could of course "select...from dual;"

Comment: Ok … I think I could fill the whole record with just one assignment …

Answer (score 1):

Comment 1:

> At certain point I get two values that I have to move to my record
>   variable.
>
> SELECT ( ,  ) INTO TARGET_REC

Comment 2:

> Good, but my values didn't come from a table - they are simple
>   variables that I got from string operations or arithmetic operations.

If I could understand from the above 2 comments, you want to fill the `collection` with string value and then use the `Collection` in a `Select` Statement to fill another collection variable.

Of-course you can fill the `collection` using string as shown below, however you there is no need of a `SELECT` statement to move the value of already populated collection to another. See below demo & read inline comments to understand more.

```
declare 
  type work_rec is record(
                         string1  varchar2 (21),  
                         number1  number  (05)
                         );

  type target_rec is table of work_rec index by pls_integer;

   v_target_rec  target_rec;

   var   target_rec;

begin   
   -- Assiging values to the collection elements more than once
   v_target_rec(1).string1 := 'ABC'; --<-- first Element
   v_target_rec(1).number1 := 2;    

   v_target_rec(2).string1 := 'CDE'; --<-- Second Element
   v_target_rec(2).number1 := 4;

   --Displaying record elements
   for rec in 1..v_target_rec.count
   Loop
      dbms_output.put_line( 'rec=(' || v_target_rec(rec).string1 || ',' || v_target_rec(rec).number1 || ')' );
   End loop; 

   /* This part is simply reduced by using assignment operator below***
   SELECT (<PROPER STRING VALUE> , <PROPER NUMBER VALUE> ) INTO TARGET_REC 
   */

   var := v_target_rec; --<--replacement of Select Statement.

   for rec in 1..var.count
   Loop
      dbms_output.put_line( 'New-rec=(' || var(rec).string1 || ',' || var(rec).number1 || ')' );
   End loop; 

End;
```